# Decode URL (percent decoding)

Tags: key-bindings, replace

Other editors I have used are able to decode URLs. For example these can take a
string like this:

```
https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/osproc#waitForExit%2CProcess%2Cint
```

and produce this:

```
https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/osproc#waitForExit,Process,int
```

I thought about using this:

```
%s/%2C/,/g
```

but then it fails with other strings:

```
https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/osproc#startProcess%2Cstring%2Cstring%2C
openArray%5Bstring%5D%2CStringTableRef%2Cset%5BProcessOption%5D
```

Is a better option available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a naive solution, but in general I prefer limited simple solutions to
robust complicated solutions. So maybe this will be helpful to someone:

```
func URL_Decode()
   sub/%2C/,/ge
   sub/%3A/:/ge
   sub/%5B/[/ge
   sub/%5D/]/ge
endfunc

nmap c :call URL_Decode()<CR>
```

Answer (score 5):

tpope's [unimpaired plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/) defines some (I think experimental) mappings for this:

```
ENCODING AND DECODING                           *unimpaired-encoding*

Each of these operations has a map that takes a motion, a map that
targets [count] lines, and a visual mode map.  The linewise variant integrates
with repeat.vim.

Mnemonic: encoding always comes before decoding; "[" always comes before "]".

                                                *[x* *[xx* *v_[x*
[x{motion}              XML encode.
[xx                     <foo bar="baz"> => &lt;foo bar=&quot;baz&quot;&gt;
{Visual}[x

                                                *]x* *]xx* *v_]x*
]x{motion}              XML decode.  HTML entities are handled as well.
]xx
{Visual}]x

                                                *[u* *[uu* *v_[u*
[u{motion}              URL encode.
[uu                     foo bar => foo%20bar
{Visual}[u

                                                *]u* *]uu* *v_]u*
]u{motion}              URL decode.
]uu
{Visual}]u

                                                *[y* *[yy* *v_[y*
[y{motion}              C String encode.  Backslash escape control
[yy                     characters, quotation marks, and backslashes.
{Visual}[y

                                                *]y* *]yy* *v_]y*
]y{motion}              C String decode.
]yy
{Visual}]y
```

Answer (score 2):

The following finds `%` followed by two hexadecimal digits, and replaces them with the corresponding character:

```
:%s/%\(\x\x\)/\=nr2char('0x' .. submatch(1))/ge
```

This is not really fully correct, for example an url like `/€` is encoded as `/%E2%82%AC` since the € character consists of three bytes; to fix this you can use `iconv()` to convert it to UTF-8 (or any other multibyte encoding you happen to be using):

```
:%s/%\(\x\x\)/\=iconv(nr2char('0x' .. submatch(1)), 'utf-8', 'latin1')/ge
```

Which is a bit more typing and a bit slower.

Comment: this failed for me with errors like 
`E15: Invalid expression: . submatch(1))`
`E116: Invalid arguments for function nr2char('0x' .. submatch(1))`
`E15: Invalid expression: nr2char('0x' .. submatch(1))`

Comment: Both patterns work for me with `vim --clean` @törzsmókus; I guess there's something in your vimrc? Or maybe you're using a (very) old version of Vim?

Comment: is 8.0 considered very old?

Answer (score 2):

If you have nodejs installed, you can shell out and use the js global `decodeURIComponent`:

```
:'<,'>!node -e 'console.log(decodeURIComponent(process.argv[1])))' -- `cat`
```

Comment: this has a syntax error (too many closing round brackets) and also some more serious bug because after removing that bracket it clears anything